# android get latitude and longitude only once

Tags: android, gps, location, latitude-longitude

I need to get for my app only when clicking a button the current latitude and longitude and save them.
I tried using `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()` with the google api but coudn't get anything in return, it's not even calling the function (`onFailure` also doesn't seem to work)

What function should I use and how?

edit:

this is my code:

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {                              
                            if (location != null) {
                                myLocation = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                                myLocation += Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            myLocation = "Error in location";
                        }
                    });
```

I don't have any errors.

Comment: post your log errors

Comment: I have added the code, there are no errors, after the function is used `myLocation` is still NULL.

Comment: print this e in log and see it

Comment: It's like the function doesn't work at all, not the `onSuccess` nor `onFailure`